# Regexp at least 8 symbols and only one uppercase character

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression for a string with has at least 8 symbols and only one uppercase character. Java

For example, it should match:

- Asddffgf
- asdAsadasd
- asdasdaA

But not:

- adadAasdasAsad
- AsdaAadssadad
- asdasdAsadasdA

I tried this: `^[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*$` This works good, but I need at least 8 symbols.

Then I tried this: `(^[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*$){8,}` But it doesn't work

Comment: Which platform? Check out lookahead assertions.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself so far? What went wrong?

Comment: You can probably also use `^(?=.{8})[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*$).{8,}$`

https://regex101.com/r/zTrbyX/6

Explanation:

`^` - Anchor to the beginning of the string, so that the following lookahead restriction doesn't skip anything.

`(?= )` - Positive lookahead; assert that the beginning of the string is followed by the contained pattern.

`[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*$` - A sequence of any number of characters that are not capital letters, then a single capital letter, then more non capital letters until the end of the string. This insures that there will be one and only one capital letter throughout the string.

`.{8,}` - Any non-newline character eight or more times.

`$` - Anchor at the end of the string (possibly unnecessary depending on your requirements).

Answer (score 0):

In your first regex `^[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*$` you could append a positive lookahead `(?=[a-zA-Z]{8,})` right after the `^`.

That will assert that what follows matches at least 8 times a lower or uppercase character.

[`^(?=[a-zA-Z]{8,})[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/DPrs4A/1)